# PHP form submit - remote address

Tags: php, html, forms, apache

I'm setting up a new web server, and there's a slight problem.

Whenever I try to use a simple post form (ie):

```
<form method="POST" action="http://IP/comments.php">

<p><label>Email: </label>
<input type="text" name="login_email" />
</p>

<p>
<input type="submit" value="Login" />
</p>

</form>
```

The browser redirects to my remote address instead of comments.php. What is the problem here?

Comments.php:

```
<?php echo "This is an empty page"; ?>
```

**Note that if the target is an html file, the form executes. So the problem appears to be sending post data to a PHP file**

Comment: I removed the PHP tag. There is no PHP here.

Comment: It is not possible. Is the code you show the same one you could see if open `html source` in the browser?

Comment: Do you have a `<base href="` in place?

Comment: I tagged this as php because I believe it is a php problem. The GET method works, as does any output sent to PHP_SELF.

Comment: @user1139980: `I tagged this as php because I believe it is a php problem` -- but there is not even a char related to php in your question. In the same way you could tag your question with `electronics` just because your code works on computer

Comment: The form submit is going to a php.

Comment: @user1139980: so what? The form submit goes to the wrong place (you said that). Your php doesn't even being called

Comment: If you enter the wrong thing into your form, this will happen. Also, if you are not coding the PHP script correctly, this will happen, too. Can we see the php?

Comment: I'm entering 's' into the form. Doing no post-processing. PHP target exists but is blank <? //  ?>. PHP on the server works fine.

Comment: put the full URL to the comments.php in the action. ex: `<form method="POST" action="http://localhost/comments.php">` - Also make sure the comments.php is in the same folder as your .html file that is sending the data.  Right now your using a relative URL which expects the files in the same location.

Comment: Robert, the files are in the same location. I've tried using http://, but with no success

Comment: Wondering if this is an apache problem

Comment: Aside from the PHP vs non-PHP arguing, what code is in comments.php? It sounds like you have a redirect in there by accident.

Comment: <?php echo "This is an empty page"; ?>

Comment: i think its a server issue, probably something about the ipaddress

Comment: This is a server issue, I'm getting a 301 moved permanently when POSTing to comments.php. What is your Apache config for this site and any relevant .htaccess files?

Comment: Bingo. That was it. Stale .htaccess. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your webserver returns error code 301 when `POST`ing to `comments.php` (see below). This is not a PHP problem, but probably a configuration error. You should check your virtual host configuration files or any `.htaccess` files that might reside in the directory in question.

```
$ netcat 107.21.231.236 80      
POST /comments.php HTTP/1.1
Host: 107.21.231.236
Content-Length: 1

a
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Tue, 10 Jan 2012 03:18:28 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.21 (Amazon)
Location: http://91.49.12.86/$
Content-Length: 228
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://91.49.12.86/$">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

how about doing something like this

```
<form method="POST" action="comments.php">
```